# Dark Souls: Multi-school casting items

Tags: dark-souls

In Demon's Souls, the Talisman of Beasts allowed you to cast both magic and miracles without having to equip a different item.

Does Dark Souls have any similar items, allowing you to cast magic, miracles and pyromancies (or even at least 2 of these 3 types of spells) with a single item? If so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such item in Dark Souls.

However there are items that interchange faith for intelligence when calculating damage scaling for sorceries and vice-versa.

[Here's](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/catalyst) a list of all the spell-casting tools available in the game (The page is tabbed).

Comment: It looks like there are also catalysts which are reasonable melee weapons as well.

Comment: That is correct. The Tin Banishment Catalyst can be found early in the game if you have the Master Key and unlock the gate in New Londo which leads to Blighttown.

Comment: There are indeed no such items. I would add that Velka's Talisman is the one that scales with Intelligence, while Tin Darkmoon Catalyst is the one that scales with Faith. [Here is the updated version of the link in the answer, which was unavailable](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/spell-tools).